# asp.net ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I recently started an asp.net mvc5 project how ever I have some issues with jQuery. 
I use Jquery-ui to get tabs and datetimepicker. 
I get 3 scripts errors on my sites with is the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6(anonymous function) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
Vacation:143 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function(anonymous function) @ Vacation:143m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:2J @ jquery.min.js:2
Vacation:117 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
```

And tabs, and datepicker should exist in jQuery-ui, I did google this error and it's when you do not use jQuery as jQuery-ui is just a plugin for jQuery.

But in my bundle I get jQuery this is my bundle:

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/dataTables.tableTools.js",
                    "~/Scripts/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js",
                    "~/Scripts/metronic.js",
                    "~/Scripts/layout.js",
                    "~/Scripts/demo.js",
                    "~/Scripts/table-advanced.js"
                    ));
```

In my network tab on chrome both jQuery and jQuery-ui reads in with: **304 Not Modified**
But it seems like jQuery-ui loads in before jQuery? 
[image]

Comment: First thing to do is to examine the HTML that the browser is getting, as that's what matters on the client side.

Comment: Try to make 2 bundles 1 that loads jquery and the other one that loads the other scripts... You can also try to change jquery.min.js to jquery.js ( or soemthing, look how jquery is calles in the folder tree)

Comment: @Jim Right.. How could I not think of that, now it works like a charm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert jQuery code? Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in view razor code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458523/how-to-insert-jquery-code-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-in-view-raz)

Comment: @ozil why do you think that would be a duplicate? That was posted 2 years ago..