# select all checkboxes in a razorview table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to select all the checkboxes in table on clicking the header checkbox. I don't know how to do that. This is what I have done so far.

```
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SNumber)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.PartNumber)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Transfer)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditDetails", new { id = item.PartNumber }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.PartNumber }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" })
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
<script>
    $('#selectAll').click(function (e) {
        $(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
</script>
```

This is what the console is returning :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

How do I get past it? I am new to MVC. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: Please change your javascript to  $('#myTable').find('td input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.prop('checked'));

Comment: @Ripun no, there's no need for that, OP's code will work as-is - see my comment below with demo link. Although, your version would be a tiny bit more efficient for the JS engine to process, but it's not actually a _problem_ the way it is now.

Comment: "I don't know how to do that". I think you do. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ofw0rn8/ your code already works, assuming that the Razor CheckBoxFor outputs what you'd expect it to. The only thing that's possibly missing from your functionality is that if the user un-checks an individual checkbox again, logically it should also uncheck the "select all" box at the same time. But that's a separate line of code you need to write. There's nothing actually wrong with what you've written so far. If it's somehow not working for you, you'll need to give us more info, e.g. any console errors etc.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, there are no errors in console. Neither when the page is rendered, nor when I check the main checkbox.

Comment: As @ADyson - the code you have shown works, so its not working for you then its something you have not shown causing the issue.

Comment: @ADyson, there are no errors in console. And yes, I have yet to implement 'uncheck all', just doing one thing at a time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, and what would that thing be that I have not shown? The only thing left was console errors. But there aren't any.

Comment: Also, I have tested it on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Ok well, what you've shown us does not allow us to reproduce your issue, so it's hard for us to help you any further. Clearly you have missed some important detail, but we can't guess what it is. Perhaps you can take my JSFiddle and modify it until it reproduces your problem, then we can understand the nature of the issue. (Check your page's source code to see what HTML it is actually outputting from the Razor code and use that - JavaScript/jQuery can only operate on the final HTML delivered to the browser, it does not know about C#/Razor code, so try to take that out of the equation).

Comment: Start by debugging the script - for example, what does `cnsole.log($(this).closest('table').find('td input:checkbox').length);` return?

Comment: Oh I got something. This is what console is returning : `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Details:242600`

Comment: Ok so you _do_ have a console error. If you haven't already worked it out (you can paste the error into google and get 1000s of results about it), it means you haven't included jQuery in your page.

Comment: You can see [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined) and hundreds of others, for instance. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458523/how-to-insert-jquery-code-uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined-in-view-raz) is a more MVC-specific one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

means jQuery is not included. First, check you have correctly included in your **BundleConfig.cs** file like this

```
    public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        // ... more code
        // This is the line that include jQuery
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        // ... more code

    }
}
```

You will have to confirm that you have actually a file named ***jquery-versionnumber.js*** in your **Script** folder. ***versionnumber*** can be any version you want to work with.
Then, verify that somewhere in your views (in your **_Layout.cshtml** by default) you have included the script, like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Notice the **~/bundles/jquery** string is the same in both the ***cs*** file and the ***cshtml*** view. Rerun and verify in your browser that jQuery file is actually included.